# Solve Sequence Alignment using memoization in OCaml cannot get correct answer

Tags: dynamic, recursion, ocaml, dynamic-programming, memoization

I used Hashtbl to store the `(int*string*string)` which is the answer of the question. However, when I run the answer is not correct. I think it is skipping some values and did not calculate them.

This is my code:

```
let solve_memo (x:string) (y:string) : (int*string*string)  =
    let x_len = String.length x in
    let y_len = String.length y in
    let tbl_size = x_len * y_len in
    let tbl = Hashtbl.create tbl_size in
    let case1 xi yi =
        if x.[xi] = y.[yi] then 1 else -1
    in
    let choose_max (pt1,strxi,stryi) (pt2,strx2,stry2) (pt3,strx3,stry3) =
        if pt1>pt2 then
            if pt1>pt3 then (pt1,strxi,stryi)
            else (pt3,strx3,stry3)
        else 
            if pt2>pt3 then (pt2,strx2,stry2) 
            else (pt3,strx3,stry3)
    in
    let rec aux xi yi (pt,strx,stry) =
    if (xi = x_len && yi = y_len) then (pt,strx,stry)
    else
    if xi = x_len then 
        (
            pt + (-2 * (y_len - yi)),
            String.concat "" [strx; String.make (y_len - yi) ' '],
            String.concat "" [stry; String.sub y (yi) (y_len - yi)]
        )
    else if yi = y_len then
        (pt + (-2 * (x_len - xi)),
        String.concat "" [strx; String.sub x (xi) (x_len - xi)],
        String.concat "" [stry; String.make (x_len - xi) ' ']
        )
    else 
        try
        Hashtbl.find tbl (xi,yi)
        with _ ->
        let r1 = aux (xi+1) (yi+1) (pt+(case1 xi yi), String.concat "" [strx; Char.escaped x.[xi]] , String.concat "" [stry; Char.escaped y.[yi]]) in
        let r2 = aux (xi+1) yi ((pt-2), String.concat "" [strx; Char.escaped x.[xi]] , String.concat "" [stry; " "]) in
        let r3 = aux xi (yi+1) ((pt-2), String.concat "" [strx; " "] , String.concat "" [stry; Char.escaped y.[yi]]) in
        let r = choose_max r1 r2 r3 in
        let _ = Hashtbl.add tbl (xi,yi) r in
        r
in aux 0 0 (0,"","")
;;
```

When I print the value that is found in the hashtbl, it repeats 2-3 values that is likely to be created at the beginning of the iterations.
Thank you.

*ADD:*

This is the original naive solve function, I wanted to add a Hashtbl to make it faster but it returns wrong result

```
let solve (x:string) (y:string) : (int*string*string)  =
let x_len = String.length x in
let y_len = String.length y in
let rec aux xi yi (pt,strx,stry) =
let case1 xi yi =
    if x.[xi] = y.[yi] then 1 else -1
    in
    let choose_max (pt1,strxi,stryi) (pt2,strx2,stry2) (pt3,strx3,stry3) =
        if pt1>pt2 then
            if pt1>pt3 then (pt1,strxi,stryi)
            else (pt3,strx3,stry3)
        else 
            if pt2>pt3 then (pt2,strx2,stry2) 
            else (pt3,strx3,stry3)
    in
    if xi = x_len then 
        (
            pt + (-2 * (y_len - yi)),
            String.concat "" [strx; String.make (y_len - yi) ' '],
            String.concat "" [stry; String.sub y (yi) (y_len - yi)]
        )
    else if yi = y_len then
        (pt + (-2 * (String.length x - xi)),
        String.concat "" [strx; String.sub x (xi) (x_len - xi)],
        String.concat "" [stry; String.make (x_len - xi) ' ']
        )
    else
        let r1 = aux (xi+1) (yi+1) (pt+(case1 xi yi), String.concat "" [strx; Char.escaped x.[xi]] , String.concat "" [stry; Char.escaped y.[yi]]) in
        let r2 = aux (xi+1) yi ((pt-2), String.concat "" [strx; Char.escaped x.[xi]] , String.concat "" [stry; " "]) in
        let r3 = aux xi (yi+1) ((pt-2), String.concat "" [strx; " "] , String.concat "" [stry; Char.escaped y.[yi]]) in
        choose_max r1 r2 r3
in aux 0 0 (0,"","")
;;
```

Comment: I would like to assure you, that OCaml is not broken. We're testing it every day)) Try to rewrite your code, so that it will be at least comprehensible.

Comment: This is an odd way to approach the problem. You should be thinking about each substring is a matrix, and memoizing the result of each sub-matrix (pair of substrings). You are looking forward in the matrix instead of backwards to subproblems. I recommend you solve for one cell, given that neighbors are memoized, then memoize that result in the hashtbl and return. With this basic intuition, you can see that you should query the cell that contains the answer (x_len,y_len).

Comment: Also, storing the pairs that define the alignment are going to blow memory with large enough sequences. The backtrace through the matrix is order O(n) so will not add much complexity to filling the costs and the alignment direction (O(n*n)).

Comment: Although, not the recursive solution you are looking for, the backtrace algorithm is and an isolation of the cost-function are contained in the phylocaml project (github.com/amnh/phylocaml) alignment.ml file in the FullAlign module. This is functorized so will not suite your needs, but give some direction on the simplicity of the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I just started learning OCaml and functional programming recently. There is a lot more I have to learn. I added some information but I will try and fix it using your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to easily modify this function to take a hashtbl for memoization. This is because you are passing an accumulator `(pt,strx,stry)` to a cell `(xi,yi)` (the accumulator represents the alignment of subsequences) from three different directions (`n0`.. `n2`, in the diagram below). You haven't determined which of the three is optimal until they are aligned with the rest of the sequence (`r0..r2`).

[image: alignment]

By adding memoization you are only storing the result of one such call, not the best. So your result depends on the previous cells (the accumulator from `n0..n2`) and the resursion to the optimal alignment of the rest of the sequence,`r0..r2`. Because of this, you cannot memoize the result without being exhaustive. For memoization to work, you need clear sub-problems which you don't have here.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is passing the accumulator that caused this problem. I thought I would just store the values using the accumulators for later outputs but somehow it messed up with using Hashtbl.

Comment: What I did to solve it was removing the accumulator in the auxiliary recursive function and changing the base case and recursive call a little to fit the new function